# How to add profile2 field data to a programatically created user

Tags: users

I create a user from a form (that part works fine) but no profile2 information seems to be created....

profile2_load_by_user returns an empty array which results in the below error.  Do I need to some other step to first associate an "ae_sa" profile with the newly created user?

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to profile2_save() must be an instance of Profile, instance of stdClass given, called in D:\FULLREPO\trunk\sites\all\modules\sps_users\sps_users.module on line 115 and defined in profile2_save() (line 291 of D:\FULLREPO\trunk\sites\all\modules\profile2\profile2.module).

```
...
$account = user_save(null, $new_user);
$obj_user = user_load($account->uid) ;
$profile2 = profile2_load_by_user($obj_user) ;
$profile2["ae_sa"]->field_full_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"] = $fullname;
$profile2["ae_sa"]->field_title_role[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"] = $titlerole;
$profile2["ae_sa"]->field_company[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"] = $ucompany;
$profile2["ae_sa"]->field_bio[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"] = $bio;
profile2_save($profile2["ae_sa"]) ;
```

Comment: You using Drupal7? If so, Why not use the field-able profile fields that come "out-of-the-box"?

Comment: Working on a project begun by someone else, switching at this point is not an option

Answer (score 5):

You need to create the new user's profile:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'ae_sa');
if(empty($profile)) {
  $profile = profile2_create(array(
    'type' => 'ae_sa',
    'uid' => $user->uid,
  ));
}

// Fill fields
$profile->field_full_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"] = $fullname;
$profile->field_title_role[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"] = $titlerole;
$profile->field_company[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"] = $ucompany;
$profile->field_bio[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"] = $bio;

// Save the newly created OR updated profile
profile2_save($profile);
```

Comment: this is perfect answer, when user dont have profile data that time you are not able to load profile and save data , thats time you have to use 

 $profile = profile2_create(array(
    'type' => 'ae_sa',
    'uid' => $user->uid,
  ));

Answer (score 3):

You need a second variable for the `profile2_load_by_user($obj_user)` function.  What you currently get back is an array of profiles, e.g

```
'candidate' => Profile object,
'person' => Profile object,
'student' => Profile object
```

You need to specify the profile in the call and then you just get a profile object back.  Then you can save the profile as it is an Profile object.

e.g. `profile2_load_by_user($obj_user,'candidate');`